# How to bind text of one text input to another text input?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Essentially what I'm trying to do is to reflect what's being typed in one text input
into another:

```
class Layout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs)
        super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.larger_comment_field = TextInput(focus=True, pos=(20, Window.height / 2), size_hint=(.8, .3))
        self.larger_comment_field.bind(text=self.on_text)
        self.another_comment_field = TextInput(pos=(20, Window.height / 3), size_hint=(.8, .3))
        self.add_widget(self.larger_comment_field)
        self.add_widget(self.another_comment_field)

    def on_text(self, instance, value):
        self.another_comment_field.text = value
```

The above doesn't even display text as I'm typing it in.

Where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this happens, but `focus` is the problem. Try changing:

```
self.larger_comment_field = TextInput(focus=True, pos=(20, Window.height / 2), size_hint=(.8, .3))
```

to:

```
    self.larger_comment_field = TextInput(pos=(20, Window.height / 2), size_hint=(.8, .3))
    self.larger_comment_field.bind(parent=self.set_focus)
```

and add a new method to your `Layout` class:

```
def set_focus(self, *args):
    self.larger_comment_field.focus = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The below made it work as desired:

```
class Layout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs)
        super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.larger_comment_field = TextInput(focus=True, pos=(20, Window.height / 2), size_hint=(.8, .3))
        self.another_comment_field = TextInput(pos=(20, Window.height / 3), size_hint=(.8, .3))
        self.another_comment_field.bind(text=self.on_text)
        self.add_widget(self.larger_comment_field)
        self.add_widget(self.another_comment_field)

    def on_text(self, instance, value):
        self.larger_comment_field.text = value
```

Now whenever I type anything in another comment field I can see text being copied over the larger one.